# [screen is terminating], can`t create screen running python script

Tags: ssh, python

I was working with my python script for a telegram bot on SSH server. I had multiple screens working together in the background. Then I quitted one of the screens with `screen -X -S screenname quit`. Then I tried to create a new screen running my python script with `screen -S screenname python3 ScriptName.py` and from that moment I keep receiving [screen is terminating] when trying to create a new screen (and after that the new screen is not created). How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you confirm if the python script runs properly without `screen`

Comment: Well, it has been running properly before this problem first appeared, I just removed few lines of code, tried to refresh the script which is running and couldn`t do that. The script should be fine.

Comment: Now I can confirm. I managed to run the script with `python3 ScriptName.py` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well, now screens can also be created, everything`s fine. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Just check that your python script can be ran without errors. If it does, you shouldn`t be getting [screen is terminating].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You replied that the script was running properly and then put this as an answer?

Comment: Yes. Didn`t know the other way to close the question